# unexpected T_PUBLIC error

Tags: php, oop

```
class Index extends Controller{ 

    public function first_index(){
        parent::__construct();
        public $name = 'tiko';
        $this -> view -> render('index/template','index/index');
    }
}
```

Error:

```
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_PUBLIC in
Z:\home\localhost\www\3ddproc.ru\controllers\index.php on line 6

Line 6 - public $name = 'tiko';
```

Comment: That's only allowed in the class declaration context, not in code blocks.

Answer (score 2):

you should set $name inside the class, not the function.

in the function you can set it to have any value you want, but declaration must be in the class root scope

```
class Index extends Controller{ 
    public $name;

    public function first_index() {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->name = 'tiko';
        $this -> view -> render('index/template','index/index');
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Public, protected, and private provide scope resolution for class functions (methods) and member variables remove `public $name = 'tiko';` from inside the function instead put outside or before the function

```
class Index extends Controller{ 
 public $name = 'tiko';
    public function first_index(){
        parent::__construct();

        $this -> view -> render('index/template','index/index');
    }
}
```